# send XML data to server from j2me application

Tags: xml, java-me

I am trying to send request data from a j2me application to server , I can't find any suitable solution to convert java object to xmlObject .

How can I convert java object to xml format in J2ME ?? please suggest appropriate solution.

Answer (score 1):

J2ME reflection is limited to invoke public constructors, so there is no way that a library can get your POJOs and, based on getters and setters, automatically generate an XML.
But you can do it manually. For example, to convert

```
class Person { String name; int yearBorn; }
```

to

```
<person><name>My Name</name><yearBorn>1978</yearBorn></person>
```

add below method to `Person` class:

```
public String toString() {
  StringBuffer sb = new StringBuffer("<person>");

  if (name == null) {
    sb.append("<name/>");
  } else {
    sb.append("<name>").append(name).append("</name>");
  }

  if (yearBorn == 0) {
    sb.append("<yearBorn/>");
  } else {
    sb.append("<yearBorn>").append(yearBorn).append("</yearBorn>");
  }

  sb.append("</person>");

  return sb.toString();
}
```

Do this for all classes and attributes you need to export as XML.